# Altering the output value of a SelectList in DropDownListFor in MVC View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html.dropdownlistfor, selectlist

I have this code inside my form:

```
<div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(c => c.ClosingHourId)
        @Html.DropDownListFor(c => c.ClosingHourId, new SelectList(Model.ClosingHours, "Id", "Time"), "Select time", new { @class = "form-control" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(c => c.ClosingHourId)
    </div>
```

The "Time" property is of type DateTime, so when I click the dropdown list on my page I see full dates and times, but the thing is I want to display only the hours, without the dates, so I want to use something like `Time.ToString("H:mm")` but I don't know where can I write this so it will work. Maybe the right approach would be to add something like `[Display(Name = Time.ToString("H:mm"))]` annotation in my ClosingHour Model? I'm not sure if it's possible.

My View Model:

```
public class CinemaFormViewModel
    {
        public int? Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(255)]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Address { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Total Seats")]
        public int TotalSeats { get; set; }

        public IEnumerable<OpeningHour> OpeningHours { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Opens At")]
        public byte? OpeningHourId { get; set; }

        public IEnumerable<ClosingHour> ClosingHours { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Closes At")]
        public byte? ClosingHourId { get; set; }
}
```

My ClosingHour Model:

```
public class ClosingHour
    {
        public byte Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public DateTime Time { get; set; }
    }
```

The Action inside the controller which calls the view:

```
public ActionResult New()
        {
            var openingHours = _context.OpeningHours.ToList();
            var closingHours= _context.ClosingHours.ToList();

            var viewModel = new CinemaFormViewModel
            {
                OpeningHours = openingHours,
                ClosingHours = closingHours
            };
            return View("CinemaForm", viewModel);
        }
```

Comment: Can you post  Model and action to create the view, pls

Comment: I've added them now.

Answer (score 0):

change you by adding string time property

```
public class ClosingHour
    {
        public byte Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public DateTime Time { get; set; }

        [NotMapped]
        public string ShortTime { get; set; }
    }
```

action

```
public ActionResult New()
        {

  var closingHours= _context.ClosingHours.ToList();
 var openingHours = _context.OpeningHours.ToList();
          
closingHours.ForEach(i=> i.ShortTime=i.Time.ToShortTimeString());
openingHours.ForEach(i=> i.ShortTime=i.Time.ToShortTimeString());

// or you can try
closingHours.ForEach(i=> { 
                i.ShortTime=i.Time.ToShortTimeString();
                i.Time=null;
                 });
openingHours.ForEach(i=> { 
                i.ShortTime=i.Time.ToShortTimeString();
                i.Time=null;
                 });

  var viewModel = new CinemaFormViewModel
   {
 OpeningHours = openingHours,
  ClosingHours = closingHours
   };
            return View("CinemaForm", viewModel);
 }
```

view

```
....
  @Html.DropDownListFor(c => c.ClosingHourId, 
new SelectList(Model.ClosingHours, "Id", "ShortTime"), "Select time", new { @class = "form-control" })
.....
```